# run method and store it one variable before each test in Nunit

Tags: nunit

I need to run a method before each test Like how before method works in TestNg.

What I am expecting is  I need to take the Testname and find the relevant test data and store it variable.  Currently I have included that step in Test.   But it would be good to have to reduce a line of code in each test.

is it possible in Nunit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup** attribute is used to provide a common set of functions that are performed just before **each test** method is called. You can also get the Method name from *TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName*. There are also other properties on Test like Arguments or FullName depending on what you need.

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var testName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName;
    TestContext.WriteLine($"SetUp for {testName}");
}
```

**Alternately**, you can also use *TestCaseData* class which provides extended test case information for a parameterized test.

```
public class DemoClass {
    
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataClass), nameof(MyDataClass.DivideTestCases))]
    public int DivideTest(int n, int d)
    {
        return n / d;
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataClass), nameof(MyDataClass.AddTestCases))]
    public int AddTest(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

public class MyDataClass
{
    public static IEnumerable DivideTestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(12, 3).Returns(4);
            yield return new TestCaseData(12, 2).Returns(6);
            yield return new TestCaseData(12, 4).Returns(3);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable AddTestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(10, 15).Returns(25);
            yield return new TestCaseData(12, 10).Returns(22);
            yield return new TestCaseData(14, 5).Returns(19);
        }
    }
}
```